# why is emacs allowing multiple instances?

Tags: emacs

Around the time I fresh installed Ubuntu 12.04, I noticed that I can start multiple instances of Emacs.  I find this annoying because I will think that a buffer should be open, but I'm in the wrong Emacs window.  I may have changed something in .emacs, but I really don't think I did.  I also reverted all of my customizations that are stored in ~/.emacs.d/custom.el.  Emacs previously would give some error about another emacs server being open when I would attempt to start an additional instance of it, but it no longer does this.  Any ideas on how to restore this behavior?

Comment: Implement it this way to avoid the warning:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397323/how-to-avoid-the-message-of-server-start-while-opening-another-emacs-session

Answer (score 5):

You are always *allowed* to start another instance.  If you don't *want* to start another instance, then run `emacsclient` instead of `emacs` and the file will be opened in the current instance instead.

Answer (score 0):

Previously, I would get the following error:

```
Warning (server): Unable to start the Emacs server.
There is an existing Emacs server, named "server".
To start the server in this Emacs process, stop the existing
server or call `M-x server-force-delete' to forcibly disconnect it.
```

Since I started having problem described in this question, this error message had not been coming up.  I managed to get it back though, and I did it by putting `(server-start)` in my ~/.emacs.